# How to fix Conda Proxy configuration error? (.netrc and _PROXY)

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I have Ubuntu for Windows installed and use it to access a remote server for my work.
I am trying to install sra-tools library in a conda environment (Server has miniconda installed) but it keeps throwing the error:

```
    $ conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 sra-tools         Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

    ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration. Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory, any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy configuration settings.
```

I am VERY NEW to bash and this complete field in general so please keep that in mind. I am still learning. If I missed out on some info just ask.

Comment: Welcome to SO kabirium! What version of `conda` are you running? There's an [open issue on the conda repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9497) mentioning a similar problem with 4.7.12. Does a similar error happen with other conda commands (e.g. `conda create -n newenv python=3.7`)?

Comment: Conda version 4.9.2
Yes, a similar error pops up with other such commands as well.

Answer (score -6):

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).